# JAX-WS timeout problem

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I've published web service endpoint on Sun light weight http server. The server is running with ThreadPool executors for the connection (`Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`).
I'm also using regular web service client (also JAX-WS).

It seems that for every call that exceed 5 minutes the server (or the client) ends the current call thread and open a new one. In the server it looks like a new connection was established and trying to run the same action.

This only happens once, meaning the "second call" might exceed 5 minutes.

Is there a default timeout for a connection ? Is there a way to configure it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was able to find a hack by using the information that Pascal provided (Thanks !).
You could override the idle time of the http server by setting a system property  -sun.net.httpserver.idleInterval.

Answer (score 5):

With the light weight http server, a connection would become idle after 5 mn. The implementation (have a look at [`ServerImpl`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/net/httpserver/ServerImpl.java.html) and [`ServerConfig`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/net/httpserver/ServerConfig.java.html)) closes the idle connections and there is currently no public property to set this idle timeout. If you want this kind of control, you may want to use a servlet container. Or you could use [Jetty (which provides a SPI) instead of Sun default HttpServer](http://tech-eureka.blogspot.com/2009/10/jax-ws-inside-jetty.html).

Answer (score 1):

I would normally expect this to be a client-side issue (however - check Pascal's answer). The clients will have a defined timeout value and would bail out on an operation taking too long.

e.g. in [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) you can define the connection timeout, and the read timeouts separately (see [the configuration guide](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/preference-api.html)).

If the method truly takes 5 mins or more, I would look at how to break that operation down into more discrete operations, each taking a shorter period of time. Or do the processing in the background, and give the client a ticket such that they can receive their results at a later time without maintaining a connection.

Alternatively, you *may* be able to set an infinite timeout, but I wouldn't recommend this, since your client ideally should be able to identify when your server isn't responding due to problems/misconfiguration etc.

Comment: You can also define timeout properties for the web service client that I'm using:
Map<String, Object> requestContext = bp.getRequestContext();    
requestContext.put(JAXWSProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, <int time>);
requestContext.put(JAXWSProperties.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, <int time>);
However, this didn't help.

Comment: @Brian This is actually not a client-side issue.

Comment: @Pascal - noted (I've not looked at your links provided yet). Do you know if Jetty doesn't bail on idle connections in a similar fashion ? Note that I've edited my answer appropriately (!) but I think for a 5 min operation, the issue of client timeout will come into play at some stage, hence I've not deleted it.

Comment: @Tal The *default* timeout of a JAX-WS client is `0` (infinite).

Comment: Interesting. Note my comments above re. infinite timeouts.

Comment: @Brian Hmm... Good question about Jetty, not 100% sure, need to check that. Now, I totally agree that it would be a good thing to set a finite client timeout (and to not use the "infinite" default) anyway.